# Hibernate created postgreSQL tables with prefix (public.)

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I used hibernate to create postgreSQL tables from classes.

all the created tables are named : **public.xyz**

for example , if the entity named **student**, then the created table name is **public.student**

class code :

```
@Entity(name="STUDENT")

@SequenceGenerator
(name = "default_sequence", sequenceName = "STUDENT_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)

public class Student extends BaseModel { ... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prefix before the `.` character represents the schema where the table is located.

In postgreSQL as in most of SQL Database, when you create a table, you may specify the belonging schema of the table. 
And in the postgreSQL case, if the schema is not specified, the schema used by default is the `public` schema. It is a schema created automatically in any  postgreSQL database.

> By default, such tables (and other objects) are automatically put
>   into a schema named "public". Every new database contains such a
>   schema.

Source : [postgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-schemas.html)

Comment: Note that you can create a table called `public.xyz`, but it's name would have to be enclosed in double quotes: `CREATE TABLE public."public.xyz" ...`

Answer (score 2):

Text before the dot is not literally the table name, it's name of a schema. *public* is the default schema of Postgres - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-schemas.html